# Struts 2 Acceptable Parameter's Names

Tags: java, configuration, parameters, struts2, interceptor

In order to take control of the parameters which an action accept you must:

Make your action implement `ParameterNameAware` like:

```
public class sample implements ParameterNameAware(){

    public boolean acceptableParameterName(String parameterName) {  
       if (("amount".equals(parameterName) || 
            "sourceAccount".equals(parameterName) ||
            "destinationAccount".equals(parameterName))
            return true;
        else
           return false;
    }

}
```

This method is called for the excluded properties of `param` properties.

So, you need to configure `params` interceptor to exclude *all* parameters, so the `acceptableParameters` get the chance to be called by `params` interceptor.

```
<interceptor-ref name="params">
    <param name="excludeParams">\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\(\d+\))|(\['\w+'\])|(\('\w+'\)))*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Am I correct?! This seems some how strange for me (Excluding *all* parameters and then adding them in each action).

Comment: I'm also using ParameterNameAware but didn't have to configure excludeParams

Comment: I am using Struts 2.3.15.3 and the acceptableParameter is not called if I do not exclude it first. May by your version is old. If so I suggest to upgrade it ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Struts2 `params` interceptor behavior against accepting or declining parameters could be extended via the `ParameterNameAware` action. All parameters are handled by this interceptor if they are accepted or ignored if they are excluded. The extension point checks for accepted parameters. If they are accepted by the interceptor then they are passed, nevertheless additional checks is performed by calling `acceptableParameterName` but it useless if parameter is accepted by the interceptor. On the other hand if parameter is excluded by the interceptor then calling this method makes a power. Coexisting both methods looks strange because they are designed to be mutually exclusive.