# datepicker plugin of jQuery does not send the value to backend in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, model-driven, struts2-interceptors

I am using jQuery to show calendar, it perfectly work but when I submit the form backend does not receive the result >> result is `null`.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
```

**JSP:**

```
   ...
   <s:textfield id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
   ...
```

**Java:**

```
  private String datepicker; 

  public String getDatepicker() {
      return datepicker;
  } 

  public void setDatepicker(String datepicker) {
     this.datepicker = datepicker;
  }
```

**Generated HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="" name="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is empty for your textfield, so you might try to set the value

```
<s:textfield id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="%{datepicker}"/>
```

and make sure the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) is configured to the action that submits the form enclosed the textfield above.

Comment: I added the %{datepicker} and am using ModelDriven to catch the values of my form. Although, I am able to retrieve the value of all the values, I can not retrieve values of datepicker.

Comment: Is `setDatepicker` being invoked?

Comment: it seems not, although all other fields of the ModelDriven object get populated.

Comment: Try to set it without `ModelDriven`, it adds unnecessary complexity to the code.

Comment: the problem was with the modeldriven but I am not sure why!

Comment: Probably your interceptor stack needs modification. But it all looks useless without actual code. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21282401/573032) answer if your names clashes with value stack. I don't know what them has downvoted it's proven and tested solution.

Comment: If I didn't miss anything from you conversation, the problem wasn't related to the jQuery plugin at all and it was just a problem with the test field ? If that is the case maybe you could rephrase the question to focus on a Struts 2 action ot being able to get the value from a text field...