# struts2 jquery grid data not loaded when implements model driven

Tags: struts2, jqgrid

My web application not loading data when I implements model driven in action class. It works fine when remove modeldriven.
action class :

```
 package action;

import action.UserBean;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

import service.OrganisationBo;
import model.AtDivision;
import model.AtOrganisation;

public class OraganisationAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<UserBean> {

    private String uname;
    private String passwd;
    private String sidx;
    // Search Field
    private String searchField;
    // The Search String
    private String searchString;
    // he Search Operation ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']
    private String searchOper;
    // Your Total Pages
    private Integer total = 0;
    //Your result List
    private List<UserBean> gridModel;
    //get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum attribute in the grid
    private Integer rows = 0;
    //Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1.
    private Integer page = 0;
    // sorting order - asc or desc
    private String sord;
    private boolean loadonce = false;
// All Record
    private Integer records = 0;
    private String includepage;
    private List<UserBean> myList;

    private String oper;
    private String id;
    private String contact;
    private String country;
    UserBean ubs = new UserBean();

    private AtOrganisation org = new AtOrganisation();
    private AtDivision div = new AtDivision();
    private List<AtOrganisation> orglist = new ArrayList<AtOrganisation>();
    OrganisationBo orgBo;
    private String aoId;

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public String getSidx() {
        return sidx;
    }

    public void setSidx(String sidx) {
        this.sidx = sidx;
    }

    public String getSearchField() {
        return searchField;
    }

    public void setSearchField(String searchField) {
        this.searchField = searchField;
    }

    public String getSearchString() {
        return searchString;
    }

    public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
        this.searchString = searchString;
    }

    public String getSearchOper() {
        return searchOper;
    }

    public void setSearchOper(String searchOper) {
        this.searchOper = searchOper;
    }

    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List<UserBean> getGridModel() {
        return gridModel;
    }

    public void setGridModel(List<UserBean> gridModel) {
        this.gridModel = gridModel;
    }

    public Integer getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(Integer rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public String getSord() {
        return sord;
    }

    public void setSord(String sord) {
        this.sord = sord;
    }

    public boolean isLoadonce() {
        return loadonce;
    }

    public void setLoadonce(boolean loadonce) {
        this.loadonce = loadonce;
    }

    public Integer getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(Integer records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    public String getIncludepage() {
        return includepage;
    }

    public void setIncludepage(String includepage) {
        this.includepage = includepage;
    }

    public List<UserBean> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(List<UserBean> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public String getOper() {
        return oper;
    }

    public void setOper(String oper) {
        this.oper = oper;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public List<AtOrganisation> getOrglist() {
        return orglist;
    }

    public void setOrglist(List<AtOrganisation> orglist) {
        this.orglist = orglist;
    }

    public String getAoId() {
        return aoId;
    }

    public void setAoId(String aoId) {
        this.aoId = aoId;
    }

    public void setOrgBo(OrganisationBo orgBo) {
        this.orgBo = orgBo;
    }

    public AtDivision getDiv() {
        return div;
    }

    public void setDiv(AtDivision div) {
        this.div = div;
    }

    public AtOrganisation getOrg() {
        return org;
    }

    public void setOrg(AtOrganisation org) {
        this.org = org;
    }



    public String execute() throws Exception {
        myList = DAO.buildList();

        setRecords(DAO.count());
        int to = (getRows() * getPage());
        int from = to - getRows();

        if (to > getRecords()) {
            to = getRecords();
        }
        if (loadonce) {
            setGridModel(myList);
        } else {
            if (searchString != null && searchOper != null && !searchString.equals("") && !searchOper.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Searching within Database");
                if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("cn")) {
                    // setGridModel(DAO.findbyName(searchString));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Searching Anywhere");
                //setGridModel(DAO.find(from, to));
                System.out.println("dili 4444");
                setGridModel(myList);
            }
        }
        total = (int) Math.ceil((double) getRecords() / (double) getRows());
        System.out.println("tot " + total);
        System.out.println(gridModel.size());
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    @Override
    public UserBean getModel() {
        return ubs;
    }
}
```

Struts.xml :

```
      <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">



        <action name="gridaction" class="action.OraganisationAction" >
          <result name="success" type="json"/>
        </action>
         </package>
</struts>
```

index.jsp :

```
 <%--
    Document   : index
    Created on : 15 Nov, 2011, 11:45:45 PM
    Author     : XCoder
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <sj:head jquerytheme="start" jqueryui="true"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:url id="remoteurl" action="gridaction"/>
        <sjg:grid
            id="sjgrid"
            caption="Grid Model"
            dataType="json"
            href="%{remoteurl}"
            pager="true"
            rowList="10,20,100"
            rowNum="5"
            navigator="true"
            width="999"
            navigatorSearchOptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"
            navigatorAddOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
            navigatorEditOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}"
            navigatorEdit="false"
            navigatorView="false"
            navigatorDelete="true"
            navigatorDeleteOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
            gridModel="gridModel" 
            editurl="%{editurl}"
            editinline="true"
            onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"

            >

            <sjg:gridColumn name="iduser"  formatter="integer"  title="iduser" key="true" hidden="true"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="uname" title="Username" editable="true" align="center"
                            editrules="{required:true}"
                            />
            <sjg:gridColumn name="passwd" title="Password" editable="true" align="center"
                            editrules="{required:true}"
                            />
            <sjg:gridColumn name="country" title="Country" editable="true" align="center"
                            edittype="select"
                            editoptions="{dataUrl:'%{selecturl}'}"
                            />
            <sjg:gridColumn name="contact" title="Contact No" editable="true" align="center"
                            editrules="{required:true,number:true,integer:true}"
                            />
        </sjg:grid>
    </body>
</html>
```

cant we implement model driven with jqgrid or my code is wrong?

EDIT: 
Just figure out that modeldriven work fine with old lib set

1. struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.8,
2. struts2-core-2.1.8.1,
3. struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-2.5.0,
4. struts2-jquery-plugin-2.5.0,
5. struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8,
6. xwork-core-2.1.6.

But when I update project into new version of struts grid is not fill with data. New lib set is as follows :

1. struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.16,
2. struts2-core-2.3.16,
3. struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.1,
4. struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0 ,
5. struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.3
6. xwork-core-2.3.16.

Anyone knows what happening here?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21282401/573032). The grid requires some properties to be set to function properly. The model is on top of the value stack doesn't have those properties.

Comment: wow. Roman C You are great.It's works.I have been stuck here since yday.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Dilis I too had same proble will you please post what you did to make it work .. ? I will award you my reputation

Comment: <interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="params">

            <param name="acceptParamNames">
                (\\[\\d+\\]\\.)*\\w+((\\.\\w+)|(\\[\\d+\\])|(\\(\\d+\\))|(\\['\\w+'\\])|(\\('\\w+'\\)))*
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<action name="*orgs" class="com.ast.action.admin.OraganisationAction"
        method="{1}">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

    <result name="grid" type="json"></result>   
</action>

As Romanc mention in his comment add to struts.xml