# Action classes hierarchy chaining from SuperAction to SubAction methods in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, action, chaining, model-driven

I'm migrating an existing Struts1 application to Struts2. I've kept the `Action`s and `ActionForm`s classes hierarchy the same.

The Struts2 actions `SuperAction` extends from `ActionSupport` and has a `ModerlDriven` member variable `SuperForm` while `SubAction` extends from `SuperAction` and has a `ModelDriven` member variable `SubForm`.

Of course, `SubForm` is a subclass of `SuperForm`. Both `SubAction` and `SuperAction` have some action methods.

`SubAction` constructor is like:

```java
    public SubAction() {
      subForm = new SubForm();
      this.superForm(this.subForm);
    }
```

Now, I've a scenario where I'm calling a `SuperAction` method from the mapping of `SubAction` like:

```xml
    <package name="sub-pkg" namespace="/subns" extends="struts-default" strict-method-invocation="true">
        <action name="subAction_*" method="{1}" class="com.company.SubAction">
          <result name="showArchived" type="chain">subAction_list</result>
          <result name="list">/jsps/list_logs.jsp</result>
          <allowed-methods>list, showArchived</allowed-methods>
        </action>
    </package>
```

The `SuperAction.showArchived()` action method sets values in its member variable `superForm.setLogMode()` and returns `String` `showArchived`, which, as can be seen from the mapping, is chaining with the `SubAction.list()` action method.

This method makes use of `SuperForm` attribute `logMode` from its member variable `subForm` and returns `String` `list` to display the `list_logs.jsp`.

The action chaining is working but it's not passing `SuperForm` attribute value `logMode`, in this case of `SuperAction` method chain to `SubAction` method.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

As a matter of fact, I found a general problem which is not specific to `SuperClass/SubClass` actions. It is occurring in general, in that using `type="chain"` is *not* working for model object in `ModelDriven` actions.

Therefore the `chain` doesn't re-populate the model properties at the end of the `chain` to the second action.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Chaining is a whole ball of wax that's generally best to avoid (IMO). It's great for simple stuff, but leads to all sorts of issues when complexity is introduced. That said: it's not clear to me what your issue is--you're saying there's a filled property in `SuperForm` that isn't reflected in `SubForm`? If that's the case we'll probably need some more info around the form classes.

Comment: See suggestions below.

Comment: @DaveNewton, `SubForm` is a subclass of `SuperForm`. What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

> The `chain` result creates a new `valueStack` with the same action bean
> and populates it from the old stack.
>
> When the chained action is invoked it has a `params` interceptor on the
> stack.
>
> When `params` interceptor is invoked it populates the action bean from
> `ActionContext` parameters.

---

What you have to the attribute populates by the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html). If you are missing some attribute check request parameters and you have getters setters to the attribute property.

> The action chaining is working but it's not passing `SuperForm` attribute value

---

Some properties to be accessible from the `ModelDriven` root should use
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282401/573032) solution.

> The [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) pushes the model on `top` of the `valueStack`, so it is easy to use it in JSP. The action object is below the
> model. So, it could be referenced directly using `[1]` prefix. See
> [OGNL basics](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl-basics.html).